# ¿Se puede hacer que el cliente introduzca desde su navegador variables? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

En todos los ejemplos que he visto siempre define las variables en el documento, nunca permite al cliente introducir sus datos. Solo puedo usar JavaScript, no puedo usar PHP. Si es necesario puedo añadir alguna etiqueta HTML. A continuación pondré un ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejemplo variables</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var variable1;
        var variable2;
        /* Lo que quiero es que estas variables las introduzca una tercera 
        persona desde un navegador ya que en la mayor parte de ejemplos los 
        hacen de la siguiente forma "var= variable3="Hola";" La idea sería 
        similar a rellenar un formulario para que finalmente te saltase un 
        cuadro modal con toda la información rellenada. */
        alert(variable1+variable2)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    /* Si es necesario aquí se podría introducir lo que sea, como un botón 
    por ejemplo. */
</body>
</html>
```

¿Es esto posible? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varias maneras de poder hacerlo. La primera y la más sencilla es utilizar el método [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) que muestra una ventana donde se puede introducir información y procesarla.

```js
var variable1 = 10;
var variable2;

variable2 = window.prompt('Introduce un numero: ');

//Convertimos en entero la cadena introducida para poder sumar enteros
var suma = variable1 + parseInt(variable2);

document.body.innerHTML = suma;
```

Otra manera, un poco más compleja, es mediante un formulario. En este caso si tendrías que agregar más etiquetas a tu html para poder ejecutarlo. Sería utilizando un `input` de tipo texto y tomando el valor de ese `input` mediante el manejo del [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Acerca_del_Modelo_de_Objetos_del_Documento), obteniendo el valor del texto con el método `document.getElementById().value` y utilizarlo para realizar la operación.

```js
function suma() {
    var variable1, variable2, resultado;
    
    variable1 = 10;

    //Coges el valor del cuadro de texto mediante su ID y el atributo value
    variable2 = document.getElementById("variable2").value;

    resultado = variable1 + parseInt(variable2);
    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<p>Variable 1 = 10</p>
<p>Introduce la variable 2:</p>

<input type="text" id="variable2">

<button type="button" onclick="suma()">Suma</button>

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta la primera opción es la respuesta que buscaba!!

Comment: Una función `suma` debe controlar los valores. Si yo escribo una letra u otra cosa que no sea un número voy a obtener `NaN` como resultado. El programador debe comprender que los usuarios son imprevisibles. La función no es *safe* en ese sentido. Saludos.

Comment: Toda la razón @A.Cedano , simplemente lo puse como ejemplo sin tenerlo en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo perfectamente. Para ello necesitarías básicamente dos cosas:

1. Agregar lo que se llama un *eventlistener* o *escuchador de eventos*. O sea, declarar en JS algo como *quiero que se ejecute este código cuando ocurra este evento*. Un evento puede ser: cuando el DOM se cargue totalmente, cuando se oprima un botón, cuando se escriba en un input, etc.
2. Dentro de ese *listener* defines el código que ha de ejecutarse. Por lo general, obtienes valores que existen en el DOM mediante el uso de `document.getElementById` o por otros medios.

He aquí un ejemplo con varios *listeners*.

```js
/*
  *Este listener se suele poner siempre al principio 
  *para que no se intente usar nada del DOM 
  *sin que éste esté cargado.
  *Todas las demás funciones suelen dentro de este bloque
 */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var elInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var variable1 = "Definida en JS";
  var variable2 = elInput.value;
  console.log(variable1 + " y " + variable2);

  /*Agregamos un listener para cada vez que se escriba algo en el input*/
  elInput.onkeyup = function() {
    var variable2 = elInput.value;
    console.log(variable1 + " y " + variable2);
  };
  
  /*Agregamos un listener para el botón*/
  var btnEnviar = document.getElementById("btnEnviar")
  btnEnviar.onclick = function() {
    var variable2 = elInput.value;
    console.log(variable1 + " y " + variable2);
  };

});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Escribe algo aquí" value="Texto de prueba" />
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, es otra manera de hacerlo. Me será útil también para futuros proyectos de la Universidad!

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @J.Adell. Considera usar siempre `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` cuando vayas a trabajar con elementos del DOM. Y aplicar buenas prácticas tales como agregar los elementos en contenedores más pequeños tales como `div`, `p`, `input`, etc, y no en el `body` directamente. Para funciones que incluyan operaciones matemáticas, también deben verificarse los valores antes de operar con ellos, de lo contrario vas a tener resultados como `NaN` si introduces valores no numéricos. Al leer la pregunta no entendí que quisieras sumar números.